# Jump to next error / code highlighted in red

Tags: vim, syntax, keyboard-shortcuts, merge-conflict-resolution

When dealing with merge conflicts it is common that the `>>>>>>` and `======` inserted by DCVS are syntactically incorrect for the file I'm in and show up as highlighted in red. When dealing with merge conflicts it would be useful to have commands to jump to these error. When I type `:cnext` I just get the message "No Errors". These are Mercurial merge conflicts so I can't use Fugitive, but I generally prefer editing merge conflicts by hand anyway.

Is there a way to jump to the next syntax error in the file? I think these errors are dictated by the syntax highlighting file.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `:lopen` to open window containing error/warning lines. After that, navigate to each of them.

The actual answer is that you can use `:lnext` to jump to the next error, or `:lprev`, or <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (those are lowercase Ls) if you have [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired), which you do, because you shouldn't use Vim without it.

This will **not** actually jump to the next red/error highlighted text group, but will jump to whatever your syntax plugin dictates is an error (and populates the location list). It is **impossible** in Vim to jump to a specific highlighting group, because no one has bothered to figure out how yet.

The plugin [SRDispHiGrp](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=848) comes close, but if you couldn't tell from the name, is too convulted and confusing for human use.

Answer (score 16):

I think you were on the right track with `:cnext`.

`:cnext` and `:cprevious` are Vim QuickFix commands; you can take advantage of them by using a code validation plugin that uses QuickFix mode, like [pyflakes.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2441) for Python, and [jslint.vim](https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim.git)/[jshint.vim](https://github.com/wookiehangover/jshint.vim.git) for JavaScript.

This will result in syntax errors being marked with squiggly red underlines, as opposed to the solid red syntax error highlighting I believe you are seeing. You should then be able to use `:cnext` and `:cprevious` to skip to the next and previous marked errors.

Answer (score 1):

`:cn` - next compiler message

`:cp` - previous

`:cl` - list

Answer (score 0):

You can use ]s (backwards) or [s (forward) depending on which direction you want to go in finding the next error. You need to be in normal mode for this to work but this is just build in vim, no extensions needed.