# How to parse mingw32-make result parsing in c++?

Tags: windows, gcc, makefile

I am invoking **mingw32-make** from my tool using `CreateProcess(..).`
After the execution i want to know the results (such as whether target is generated or if there are any compilation errors etc...) of the execution.
Can some one help me on how to parse the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually one does not *parse* the result from a compile, except as a followup to analyze the errors.  Instead (in scripts and makefiles), one uses the exit-status of the compiler, which returns a nonzero (error) code on failure.

In a makefile, unless the magic "`-`" flag precedes the command which runs a program, any exit-status will stop the build.

Error messages and diagnostics are written to the standard output.  It is possible to *parse* these messages; several text editors (e.g., [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html), [vi like emacs](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile-hlp.html#misc_commands), [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361733/vim-jump-to-next-error-code-highlighted-in-red)) can do this, positioning the cursor to the location in the source file where an error was detected.  There are several variants.  The most common uses

```
filename:line:message
```

like the `grep` program.  Some add the column number, like one of these:

```
filename:line.column:message
filename:line:column:message
```

The error messages may include multiple lines, providing additional information about the message, but in most cases the colon-separated filename, line-number and message is enough to position the cursor to the right place.