# cancel latex preview in vimrc

Tags: vim, latex, preview, vim-plugin

I am using vim to learn latex and have a big vimrc config provided below. Now I wanna get rid of live latex preview function for some reasons. The problem is even if I comment out the vim-latex-live-preview plugin and do :VundleUpdate in vim, the live preview function is still there. Have no idea where it comes from.

[image: would like \textbf{bold text} here]

```
"Use Vim settings, rather then Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" ================ General Config ====================

    set textwidth=0                 "make paste into vim easier
    set number                      "Line numbers are good
    set backspace=indent,eol,start  "Allow backspace in insert mode
    set history=1000                "Store lots of :cmdline history
    set showcmd                     "Show incomplete cmds down the bottom
    set showmode                    "Show current mode down the bottom
    set gcr=a:blinkon0              "Disable cursor blink
    set visualbell                  "No sounds
    set autoread                    "Reload files changed outside vim
    set hlsearch                    "high light search result
    set cc=80                       "get a red line reminder at column count 80
    set clipboard="*"               "the origina
    "set clipboard+=unnamed         "make vim register plus sys register,
    set cursorline                  "get a line under where cursor point
    set gcr=a:block-blinkon0        "禁止光标闪烁
    "set lines=35 columns=80 "maybe a better choice
    " autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC " 让配置变更立即生效
    set incsearch                   " 开启实时搜索功能
    set ignorecase                  " 搜索时大小写不敏感
    syntax on                       "turn on syntax highlighting
    set hidden                      " buffers exist in the background without being in a window.
                                    " http://items.sjbach.com/319/configuring-vim-right
    set nowrap                      "no, Wrap lines, I find nowrap is suitable for small screen
    set linebreak                   "Wrap lines at convenient points
    set guifont=Monaco:h16          " For MacVim


    " set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:Â· " Display tabs and trailing spaces visually

" guivim config {{{
    " 禁止显示滚动条
    set guioptions-=l
    set guioptions-=L
    set guioptions-=r
    set guioptions-=R
    " 禁止显示菜单和工具条
    set guioptions-=m
    set guioptions-=T
" }}}

"Lang & Encoding {{{
    set fileencodings=utf-8,gbk2312,gbk,gb18030,cp936
    set encoding=utf-8
    set langmenu=zh_CN
    let $LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
"language messages zh_CN.UTF-8
" }}}

" Turn Off Swap Files {{{
    set noswapfile
    set nobackup
    set nowb
" }}}

" Persistent Undo {{{
    " Keep undo history across sessions, by storing in file.
    " Only works all the time.
    " NOT WORKING: Didnt work when yanked right out of YADR
    "silent !mkdir ~/.vim/backups > /dev/null 2>&1
    "set undodir=~/.vim/backups
    "set undofile
" }}}

" Indentation  {{{
    set autoindent
    set smartindent
    set smarttab
    set shiftwidth=4
    set softtabstop=4
    set tabstop=4
    set expandtab
    set foldmethod=indent

    filetype plugin on
    filetype indent on
" }}}

" Completion  {{{
    set wildmode=list:longest
    " vim 自身命令行模式智能补全
    set wildmenu                "enable ctrl-n and ctrl-p to scroll thru matches
    set wildignore=*.o,*.obj,*~ "stuff to ignore when tab completing
    set wildignore+=*vim/backups*
    set wildignore+=*sass-cache*
    set wildignore+=*DS_Store*
    set wildignore+=vendor/rails/**
    set wildignore+=vendor/cache/**
    set wildignore+=*.gem
    set wildignore+=log/**
    set wildignore+=tmp/**
    set wildignore+=*.png,*.jpg,*.gif
" }}}

" Scrolling {{{
    set scrolloff=8         "Start scrolling when we're 8 lines away from margins
    set sidescrolloff=15
    set sidescroll=1
" }}}

" Change leader to a comma because the backslash is too far away
" That means all \x commands turn into ,x
" The mapleader has to be set before vundle starts loading all
" the plugins.
let mapleader=","


" ========================================
" Vim plugin configuration
" ========================================
"
" This file contains the list of plugin installed using vundle plugin manager.
" Once you've updated the list of plugin, you can run vundle update by issuing
" the command :BundleInstall from within vim or directly invoking it from the
" command line with the following syntax:
" vim --noplugin -u vim/vundles.vim -N "+set hidden" "+syntax on" +BundleClean! +BundleInstall +qall
" Filetype off is required by vundle
filetype off

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
"set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins

" let Vundle manage Vundle (required)
"Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

"""" MY VUNDLES """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" HEAVILY/MOSTLY taken from https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles

    " Make Git pervasive in vim ( :Gblame + Glog + many more )
    " TODO: figure out how to use
    Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

    " file navigator gutter
    Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree.git'

    " build a more useful statusline
    Plugin 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'

    " awesome syntax highlighting
    Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'

    " a complex autocomplete tool developed by a developer in google research project
    Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

    " Command+T replacement (ctrl+P)
    "Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'

    " Rails plugin ( :A mapping! )
    "Plugin 'tpope/vim-rails.git'

    " comment lines out (gc in visual mode)
    "Plugin 'tomtom/tcomment_vim.git'

    " Make it look amazing
    Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'

    " Pimped out bar at the bottom of current buffer
    "Plugin 'bling/vim-airline.git"

    " Highlights class names + methods more brightly
    " Handy for seeing syntax shape before your eyes
    "Plugin 'vim-scripts/TagHighlight.git'

    " Search everything in the current dir via :Ack
    "Plugin 'mileszs/ack.vim'

    " Enable Markdown Preview + GitHub flavored markdown
    "Plugin 'jtratner/vim-flavored-markdown.git'
    "Plugin 'nelstrom/vim-markdown-preview'

    " TODO: Figure out how to do indents intelligently
    "Plugin 'austintaylor/vim-indentobject'

    " Open a shell within vim via :ConqueTerm
    "Plugin 'skwp/vim-conque'

    " Syntax highlighting for .bats files
    "Plugin 'rosstimson/bats.vim'

    " Open up a bash shell quickly in the current window
    "map <Leader>s <esc>:ConqueTermSplit bash<cr>

    " Make Ctrl+w o, function with toggle niceness
    "Plugin 'vim-scripts/ZoomWin'

    " requires exuberant ctags
    Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'

    " A Vim Plugin for Lively Previewing LaTeX PDF Output
    " Plugin 'xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview'

    " plugin taglist
    " from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273`:w
    " comment out for the test of vundle
    "let Tlist_Show_One_File=1
    "let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow=1

    " let g:winManagerWindowLayout='FileExplorer|TagList'
    "nmap wm :WMToggle<cr>

    set completeopt=longest,menu

    " file browser, using vim command Tlist...
    Plugin 'vim-scripts/taglist.vim'

    " ctags for vim
    Plugin 'szw/vim-tags'

    " Eclim make eclipse run in handless mode o
    " visit http://eclim.org/
    " Plugin 'dansomething/vim-eclim'

    " java complete2
    Plugin 'artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2'

    " Eclim
    Plugin 'dansomething/vim-eclim'

    " indentLine
    Plugin 'Yggdroot/indentLine'

    " tabular
    Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'

"""" END OF VUNDLE PLUGINS """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on     " required!
"
" Brief help
" :BundleList          - list configured bundles
" :BundleInstall(!)    - install(update) bundles
" :BundleSearch(!) foo - search(or refresh cache first) for foo
" :BundleClean(!)      - confirm(or auto-approve) removal of unused bundles
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" NOTE: comments after Bundle command are not allowed..

"===================  PLUGIN CONFIG ==========================================

" tagbar {{{
    " 设置 tagbar 子窗口的位置出现在主编辑区的左边
    let tagbar_left=1
    " 设置显示／隐藏标签列表子窗口的快捷键。速记：identifier list by tag
    "nnoremap <Leader>ilt :TagbarToggle<CR>
    nnoremap <Leader>il :TagbarToggle<CR>
    " 设置标签子窗口的宽度
    let tagbar_width=32
    " tagbar 子窗口中不显示冗余帮助信息
    let g:tagbar_compact=1
    " 设置 ctags 对哪些代码标识符生成标签
    let g:tagbar_type_cpp = {
        \ 'kinds' : [
             \ 'c:classes:0:1',
             \ 'd:macros:0:1',
             \ 'e:enumerators:0:0',
             \ 'f:functions:0:1',
             \ 'g:enumeration:0:1',
             \ 'l:local:0:1',
             \ 'm:members:0:1',
             \ 'n:namespaces:0:1',
             \ 'p:functions_prototypes:0:1',
             \ 's:structs:0:1',
             \ 't:typedefs:0:1',
             \ 'u:unions:0:1',
             \ 'v:global:0:1',
             \ 'x:external:0:1'
         \ ],
         \ 'sro'        : '::',
         \ 'kind2scope' : {
             \ 'g' : 'enum',
             \ 'n' : 'namespace',
             \ 'c' : 'class',
             \ 's' : 'struct',
             \ 'u' : 'union'
         \ },
         \ 'scope2kind' : {
             \ 'enum'      : 'g',
             \ 'namespace' : 'n',
             \ 'class'     : 'c',
             \ 'struct'    : 's',
             \ 'union'     : 'u'
         \ }
         \ }
" }}}

" vim-latex-live-preview {{{
    "let g:livepreview_previewer = 'open -a Preview'
" }}}

" java-complete {{{
    autocmd FileType java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#OmniCppComplete
" }}}


" drawing from altercation/vim-colors-solarized  {{{
    " syntax enable
    " set background=dark
    "colorscheme solarized
    "color solarized
" }}}


" NERDTree {{{
    " Reveal current file in NERDTree with <Leader>r
    map <Leader>r <esc>:NERDTreeFind<cr>
    " 使用 NERDTree 插件查看工程文件。设置快捷键，速记：file list
    nmap <Leader>fl :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
    " 设置NERDTree子窗口宽度
    let NERDTreeWinSize=32
    " 设置NERDTree子窗口位置
    let NERDTreeWinPos="right"
    " 显示隐藏文件
    let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
    " NERDTree 子窗口中不显示冗余帮助信息
    let NERDTreeMinimalUI=1
    " 删除文件时自动删除文件对应 buffer
    let NERDTreeAutoDeleteBuffer=1
" }}}

" SYNTASTIC {{{
    "mark syntax errors with :signs
    let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
    "automatically jump to the error when saving the file
    let g:syntastic_auto_jump=0
    " set to 1 to show the error list automatically
    let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=0
    "don't care about warnings
    "let g:syntastic_quiet_warnings=0
    let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = {'level': 'warnings'}
" }}}

" YCM {{{
    " YCM 补全菜单配色
    " 菜单
    highlight Pmenu ctermfg=3 ctermbg=0 guifg=#005f87 guibg=#EEE8D5
    " 选中项
    highlight PmenuSel ctermfg=2 ctermbg=3 guifg=#AFD700 guibg=#106900
    " 补全功能在注释中同样有效
    let g:ycm_complete_in_comments=1
    " 允许 vim 加载 .ycm_extra_conf.py 文件，不再提示
    let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf=0
    " 开启 YCM 标签补全引擎
    let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files=1
    " 引入 C++ 标准库tags
    set tags+=/data/misc/software/misc./vim/stdcpp.tags
    " YCM 集成 OmniCppComplete 补全引擎，设置其快捷键
    inoremap <leader>c <C-x><C-o>
    " 补全内容不以分割子窗口形式出现，只显示补全列表
    set completeopt-=preview
    " 从第一个键入字符就开始罗列匹配项
    let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion=1
    " 禁止缓存匹配项，每次都重新生成匹配项
    let g:ycm_cache_omnifunc=0
    " 语法关键字补全
    let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax=1
    " set python semantic completion
    let g:ycm_python_binary_path = 'python'
    " here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361733/jump-to-next-error-code-highlighted-in-red
    " and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174738/youcompleteme-vim-extension-how-to-jump-to-next-error
    " try to figure out how to jump to errors with YCM
    let g:ycm_always_populate_location_list=1
" }}}
"

" javacomplete2 {{{
autocmd FileType java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
" }}}

" ====== Make tabs be addressable via Apple+1 or 2 or 3, etc
" Use numbers to pick the tab you want (like iTerm)
    " TODO: ??
    map <silent> <D-1> :tabn 1<cr>
    map <silent> <D-2> :tabn 2<cr>
    map <silent> <D-3> :tabn 3<cr>
    map <silent> <D-4> :tabn 4<cr>
    map <silent> <D-5> :tabn 5<cr>
    map <silent> <D-6> :tabn 6<cr>
    map <silent> <D-7> :tabn 7<cr>
    map <silent> <D-8> :tabn 8<cr>
    map <silent> <D-9> :tabn 9<cr>

" ctags {{{
    map <Leader>tt <esc>:TagbarToggle<cr>
    " TODO later, get open tag in new tab working
    " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks
    " map <C-\>:tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
    " map <A-]>:vsp <CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
" }}}

" Support for github flavored markdown
" via https://github.com/jtratner/vim-flavored-markdown
" with .md extensions
    augroup markdown
        au!
        au BufNewFile,BufRead *.md,*.markdown setlocal filetype=ghmarkdown
    augroup END

" =========================END OF PLUGIN CONFIG=================================

" Function {{{
" Remove trailing whitespace when writing a buffer, but not for diff files.
" From: Vigil
" @see http://blog.bs2.to/post/EdwardLee/17961
    function! RemoveTrailingWhitespace()
        if &ft != "diff"
            let b:curcol = col(".")
            let b:curline = line(".")
            silent! %s/\s\+$//
            silent! %s/\(\s*\n\)\+\%$//
            call cursor(b:curline, b:curcol)
        endif
    endfunction
    autocmd BufWritePre * call RemoveTrailingWhitespace()
" }}}

" make vim accept per project .vimrc
set exrc
set secure
```

Comment: `:h conceal`, `:h tex-conceal`

Comment: it's originally from here: https://github.com/yangyangwithgnu/use_vim_as_ide .

Comment: I learned this repository three or two years ago when I started vim. It's  pretty modified for my porpuse and I know most of statement in it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lcd047's comment, it's a build in function of vim called tex-conceal.

[image]